# Using TS literal types, what is the most straight-forward way to get a string that matches multiple patterns against a union of string literals?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, template-strings

Let's say i have the following union:

```
type T = "a.success" | "a.failure" | "b.success" | "c";
```

and I want to get a union of all strings that match two patterns at once - `${string}.success` and `${string}.failure` (in my example, the resulting union would be only `MyUnion = "a"`)

I was expecting the following syntax to work (since it does exactly what I want with union operator, but not with intersection):

```
type BothSuccessAndFailure <ID = T> = ID extends `${infer Base}.success` & `${infer Base}.failure` 
  ? Base 
  : never;
```

but this always resolves to `never`, no matter what. Switching one of the `infer Base` to `infer Base2` doesn't help either. Is there a way to make this work?

Here are two approaches that work, but aren't as clean as I would like:

```
// This gets a bit messy with increasing number of patterns to match and 
// Prettier breaking each of them into four lines. 
type Success<ID = T> = ID extends `${infer Base}.success` ? Base : never;
type Failure<ID = T> = ID extends `${infer Base2}.failure` ? Base2 : never;
type BothSuccessAndFailure
```

```
// I thought of this one while authoring this question and it's acceptable for me, but
// I still find the syntax a bit confusing, and many nested ternaries slightly annoying
type BothSuccessAndFailure<ID = T> = ID extends `${infer Base}.success`
  ? `${Base}.failure` extends T 
    ? Base
    : never
  : never;
```

Or would it perhaps be possible to make a `GetStringsPresentWithAllOfSuffixes<SourceUnion, SuffixUnion>` generic?

Comment: `${infer Base}.success & ${infer Base}.failure` is an empty intersection because no string ends with both "success" and "failure" so no string can match both patterns. But you have two approaches which work; is the problem really just that you want something cleaner than those? Both are fine.

Comment: @kaya3 Oh, of course, that's why it can't work, thanks! I only had the first approach and it was getting messy for an increasing number of match patterns. But the second one, I will probably settle with.